# How can I merge rows in Excel based on a delimiter inbetween rows?

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, merge, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet whereby I have pasted text from notepad.
The issue is that it has created a single row for each line of text.

The rows look like this:

```
|Questions|
---------------
|Question #1 %| 
|Question text|
|Portion of the same question inserted on additional row|
|Multiple choice A|
|Multiple choice B|
|Multiple choice C|
|Multiple choice D|
|Question #2 %|
```

I used this as a delimiter "%"

I'd like to use this delimiter to combine/merge the cells inbetween them into one cell.
Basically One cell per question. There are approximately 3000+ questions. I'd like to run a match to see which ones are duplicated and I cannot do this when the questions are broken up onto separate cells.

I've tried to use Text.Join, Concatenate, If statements, unfortunately my knowledge and Excel skill is poor and lacking.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Since you have Excel 2010, you won't have the `TEXTJOIN` function, and there is no `Text.Join` function. However, you do have access to Power Query -- it is a free MS supplied add-in in 2010 (and built-in in versions 2016+, I believe) so you can use that. If that is not available you can write a VBA routine. Since this is not a free code-writing service, it would be advisable to edit your question to show what you have already tried, and where you have run into problems. Suggest you use VBA or PQ as they will be simpler than formulas in Excel 2010.

Comment: Imho, if the target is "..  to run a match to see which ones are duplicated  ..." then (assuming all is pasted in column A)  do a `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1)` in B1 and drag downwards will do . right ?

Comment: correction >> should be `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)` ,  then put a filter to remove all 1.

Comment: @blane did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

Would the following approach help? I broke it down into several columns to walk you through the logic behind this.

[image]

Basically I did the following:

Column B: I removed any trailing white spaces and also the "|" symbol
Column C: I checked if the cell in Column A had the header of your question, or the body
Column D: Similar logic to column C, but this time **I started one row before** (see orange cells)
Column E: If we were at the beginning of a question, we copied cell A to cell E. If we were in the body of the question, we concatenated the previous cell from Column E to the one in column A.

You need to **place all your formulas in the orange cells** and then you can drag them down.

Formulas for each column:

Col B: =LEFT(RIGHT(TRIM(A3),LEN(TRIM(A3))-1),LEN(RIGHT(TRIM(A3),LEN(TRIM(A3))-1))-1)

Col C: =IF(RIGHT(B3,1)="%","HEAD","BODY")

Col D: =IF(RIGHT(B3,1)="%","keep","ignore")

Col E: =IF(C3="BODY",E2&" "&B3,B3)

I think you would basically be interested in the cells in yellow, which can be obtained by using the filter in Column D, setting it to "keep".

Applying the filter in Column D so you retain the cells with the whole question-answer, this gives you the results below.
Once here you can use the values in the cells from Column E to run a Duplicates analysis.
[image]